# Variable doesn't update inside composable using jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm trying out jetpack compose and have a basic textfield composable that accepts a boolean variable for validation.
However it doesn't update properly and only works at initialisation.

```
class RegistrationActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {

        var name = "zzz"

        BasicField(
            title = "Last Name",
            value = name,
            onValueChange = {name = it},
            placeholder = "Enter Last Name",
            validation = (name.length>2&&name.contains("zzz"))
        )
    }
}}
```

composable:

```
@Composable
fun BasicField(title: String,
           value: String,
           onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
           placeholder: String,
            maxLines: Int = 1,
            validation: Boolean ) {

var fieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(value)) }

BasicTextField(
    maxLines = maxLines,
    value = fieldValue,
    onValueChange = {
        fieldValue = it

        if(fieldValue.text.length>5){//this part works
            Log.e("error","valid string")
        }else{
            Log.e("error","invalid string")
        }

        if(validation){//this part doesnt work
            Log.e("error","custom validation works")
        }else{
            Log.e("error","custom validation failed")
        }


    },


) }
```

I have a basic validation inside the composable which checks for string length which works, but when the logic is from outside it doesn't work. I appreciate any help or hint thanks!

Comment: I suggest you check out with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles. Only state value can live though recompositions and trigger them, your `name` should be state too

Comment: thanks will look in to it! @PylypDukhov

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your name as state in compose. Here we have used 2 things.

1. `name` is defined as state. And it is remembered in composition. So whenever this composable function goes into re-composition, this name will not be re-assigned.
2. Used `LaunchedEffect` to execute your logs statements. So LaunchedEffect will start with a key and when they key changes, this effect will restart.

---

```
class RegistrationActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {

                // 1
        val name = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        BasicField(
            title = "Last Name",
            value = name.value,
            onValueChange = {name.value = it},
            placeholder = "Enter Last Name",
            validation = (name.value.length>2&&name.value.contains("zzz"))
        )
    }
}}
```

---

```
@Composable
fun BasicField(title: String,
           value: String,
           onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
           placeholder: String,
            maxLines: Int = 1,
            validation: Boolean ) {

    // 2
    LaunchedEffect(key = value) {
        if(value.length>5){
            Log.e("error","valid string")
        }else{
            Log.e("error","invalid string")
        }
        
        if(validation){
            Log.e("error","custom validation works")
        }else{
            Log.e("error","custom validation failed")
        }
    }
    
    BasicTextField(
        maxLines = maxLines,
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
            onValueChange(it)
            },
    ) 
}
```